# Mongo query to check whether today's date is between 2 others

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to query my db to find documents where today's date lies between `dates.start` and `dates.end`.

I'm storing the dates in unix time and using `moment().valueOf()` to get the current unix time.

```
"dates.startDate":{
    $lte: moment().valueOf()
},
"dates.endDate":{
    $gte: moment().valueOf()
}
```

The query isn't working. Could someone help me figure out why?

Comment: The query logic looks good. Failures in such queries are invariably the result of dates being stored and compared in different formats. `console.log` `startDate` and `endDate` for a document and compare formats with `moment.valueOf()`.

Comment: provide some sample documents

Comment: I was convinced that this part of the query was the problem. I found the actual problem slightly earlier in the query. Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be

```
"dates.startDate":{
    $gte: moment().valueOf()
},
"dates.endDate":{
    $lte: moment().valueOf()
}
```

Comment: That logic says *current time is **outside** of the interval* not **inside**